# assosiative array in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I wont to do something like this

```
$this->ss->assign("questions", $array); 
$this->ss->assign("questionsAns", $qsFullAns);
```

and in smarty something like this:

```
$var = $array[$qsFullAns];
```

How can I do this??

Comment: What's in $array and $qsFullAns?

Comment: $array is associative array and $qsFullAns is some variable. that is a key in $array. The answer from Deefour did the job tanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

```
{$foo.$bar}   <-- display variable key value of an array, similar to PHP $foo[$bar]
```

As for `$var = $array[$qsFullAns];`

```
{assign var=var value=$questions.$questionsAns}
```

`{$var}` is now the equilvalent in PHP of `$var = $array[$qsFullAns];`